# Firebase - simple data structure issue

Tags: android, firebase

Here's the thing :) I'm using firebase and I have a pretty simple data set.

```
SONGS
  -song1uniqueID:
    -description: "a song"
    -duration: "3"
  -song2uniqueID:
    -description: "another song"
    -duration: "2"
  -song3uniqueID:
    -description: "yet another song"
    -duration: "4"

ALBUMS
  -album1:
    -songs:
      -song1uniqueID:true
      -song2uniqueID:true
```

I structured this following the quick guide the good guys at firebase present to us.

Now, say I have a reference to `album1` how would I go about retrieving it's songs. Sure I have the keys of the songs but I need their descriptions and duration. I have not found a way to do this using firebase. 
Does anyone can help :) 
thanks in advance